# @wire fails with "newValue cannot be undefined. Observable name"

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, salesforcedx, isv

When opening a Record page containing our `LWC` component we receive this weird error message.

**This doesn't happen in our `namespaced` `SFDX scratch org` but in a subscriber org that is using the resulting managed package.**

> newValue cannot be undefined. Observable name:
>   MapWithFilterOnSubscribeBehaviorSubject <= DistinctUntilChanged <=
>   RootObservable:
>   lds.Apex:NAMESPACE:OurCtrl:loadFromApi:false:,
>   newValue: undefined

Here is the Wired method that seems to be the root cause

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import loadFromApi from '@salesforce/apex/MyCtrl.loadFromApi';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @track text = new Array();
    ...

    @wire(loadFromApi, { recordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredRecordsMethod({ error, data }) {
        if(data) {
            this.text = new Array();

            const conversations = this.format(JSON.parse(data));
            if(conversations.length > 0) {
                conversations.forEach((dialog, index) => {
                    setSomeVariables(...)
                });

                this.text[this.text.length - 1].isLastInTheSeries = true;
            }   
        }
        if(error) {
            this.showToast(error, true);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I am absolutely clueless. If you need to see more code just tell me in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would happen if your wire service returned a null value. Do not return a null value from an AuraEnabled method. Instead, throw an AuraHandledException such that you'll have an error to work with.

Comment: Awesome. But why does thing not fail in my scratch org. Is this unrelated?

Comment: @RobertSösemann It's hard to tell. You'll need to fix it so that you can get an error, then you'll know why it's returning null.